# Strange bright/white bubbles beneath LCD screen

Tags: display, macbook-pro, lcd, defective-hardware

I've got an older generation x86 Macbook Pro that has some weird white bubbles embedded in the LCD. The actual pixels seem to be working fine (not dead or stuck), and when I put colored images in those areas, the bubble-affected regions change color accordingly, but just look brighter.

It looks really bizarre as the bubbles look like they're behind the image being displayed on screen (maybe a little less than 1mm in), as if they're air bubbles suspended in a layer of gel or something (pardon the dirt and cat hair):

[image: photo of MBP screen with clusters of glowing white bubbles]

[image: photo of MBP screen with 1 strong cluster of bubbles and 2 faint ones, showing that color can still be displayed in bubble-affected regions]

[image: another shot of the same clusters of bubbles]

[image: very zoomed in shot of the first clusters of bubbles]

So what exactly is causing this, and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Top and bottom picture, is that dirt to the left of the "bubbles", or also related?

Comment: @Daniel: That's just dirt, and a long cat hair. It's actually someone else's MBP, and they haven't kept it very clean. =P

Comment: I suspect that some relatively sharp edge of something pressed against the screen at some time and damaged the structure of it.  Could be just scratches on the anti-reflective coating, or could be deeper damage.

Comment: @DanH: Possibly, but it appears on both the left and right edges of the screen, as well as fainter and smaller clusters of 1~3 bubbles in 3 other locations. It just seems odd as I've never seen this type of damage to an LCD before.

Comment: That's a weird one. :)  Maybe something has damaged the reflective backing on the LCD panel itself? On some LCD panels it's like a sticky tinfoil.  Maybe it has tears or wear in it?   But if that's the case, it seems odd that they appear brighter though.

Comment: In any event, I suspect the display is damaged, and there's likely no way to fix it.